# mouseenter and mouseout more stable results?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, mouseenter, mouseout

So I wanted to have a cool feature, where the header of a focused content area changes using the nifty color animate tool. Well, it animates just fine... but it thinks you immediate mouseout when the mouse is still inside the target around. Does anyone know how to make it stable? I was thinking about capturing the mouse and if it's inside the 'zone' do it but I don't know if that is better?

```
        // Content Hovers

        $('.large-box > *').each(function(){

            $(this).mouseenter(function(){
                $(this).find('.column-header').animate({ 'backgroundColor': '#3e84d2' }, 'slow');
            });
            $(this).mouseout(function(){
                $(this).find('.column-header').animate({ 'backgroundColor': '#455c79' }, 'slow');
            });

        });
```

**Soution:** The solution was to use `mouseleave()` instead of `mouseout()`

Comment: Your link is not working for me. Here's what it returns instead of a webpage: http://i.imgur.com/lg7h6av.png?1?5635

Comment: Oops updated. And apparently PHP isn't working. Lol

Comment: Try using mouseleave() instead of mouseout(), because mouseout() will trigger for sub-elements too... and as such should be used with mouseover() instead of mouseenter(). That may not solve the problem, but that's one issue I see right away... oh, and don't call `$this` twice, rather tack it on the end. That might just be how I do it, but it seems to work better for me that way. EDIT: here are some examples: http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Comment: I don't have the time to edit directly in the web page, but could you please try using hover instead, the syntax is .hover(function() { //HoveIn }, function() { //HoverOut });

Comment: @craniumonempty Thanks bud! That did the trick! If you want to rewrite as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: @WASasquatch np. I submitted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mouseleave() instead of mouseout(), because mouseout() will trigger for sub-elements too and should be used with mouseover() instead of mouseenter().

Examples: http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/